# Vanilla JS. Removing objects from an array within a for each method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hope you can help me. I'm trying to find an object in an array based on it's content and then once I've found that object, remove it from the array completely (So that I can then update the local storage with the newly modified array).

```
let object = JSON.parse(localStorage.items);

// returns the following: 
// [{text: 'Taco'}, {text: 'Pizza'}, {text: 'Curry'}]

object.forEach((obj, i) => {
  obj.text === 'Taco' ? object.splice(i) : console.log(`${i}: ${obj.text} is not a Taco.`);
});
```

At this point I'd expect the object array to now only contain Pizza and Curry but it still contains Taco for some reason and I am super confused! The forEach method spits out two console logs, one for Pizza and one for Curry but nothing actually happens to the Taco.

Is anyone able to help me understand why this isn't working?

Comment: Don't ever change the collection you're iterating over when you're not absolutely sure about the possible consequences.

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont change collection you are iterating over. It still in progress of iteration and you are changing collection itself.

Use Filter method of Natvie js

Const filteredValue = object.filter( obj =>  obj.text !== 'Taco')

Thanks

Comment: That makes complete sense. Until now I wasn't sure why you'd use something other than forEach but now I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You might find [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) easier to use instead:

```
const notTacos = arr.filter(obj => obj.text !== 'Taco');
```

Comment: @Minato also undoubtedly a dupe

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes, been asked so many times and answered in a very same way :P

Comment: Andy, thank you for this. I'm still getting used to Array methods and until now I didn't understand why you wouldn't use a forEach method over all of these things. Now with your code and with the above I think it makes sense. 

@Minato, Lawrence Apologies if it's been asked before/ is simple. I was under the impression Stack overflow was a community of people who are available to help people (including beginner JS developers) to grow and learn.

Comment: Yeah @ThomasHewitt, `filter` along with `map`, and `reduce`, unlike, `forEach` all return _new_ objects rather than mutating the current one. They're super useful.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is `object.splice(i)` when the second parameter (end index) is omitted it is considered as `object.length-1` since the `Taco` found at `0th` index so it removes all the elements, [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Parameters)

```js
let a = [{text: 'Taco'}, {text: 'Pizza'}, {text: 'Curry'}]
let b = [{text: 'Taco'}, {text: 'Pizza'}, {text: 'Curry'}]

a.splice(0)
b.splice(0,1)
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

But as a good practice you should never mutate ( deleting the complete element ) the array when you're iterating over it, better use `filter`

```js
let object = [{text: 'Taco'}, {text: 'Pizza'}, {text: 'Curry'}]

let final = object.filter(({ text }) => text !== 'Taco')

console.log(final)
```